# Find biggest independent subset of a connectivity matrix

Tags: r, matrix, subset, igraph

I have two groups linked by a connectivity matrix like the following:

```
#
#   X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6
#   1   0   0   0   0   0  V1
#   1   1   1   0   0   0  V2  
#   0   1   0   0   0   0  V3
#   0   0   1   0   0   0  V4
#   0   0   0   1   0   0  V5
#   0   0   0   1   0   0  V6
#   0   0   0   0   1   0  V7
#   0   0   0   0   1   1  V8
#   0   0   0   0   1   0  V9
#   0   0   0   0   0   1  V10
#
```

So X1 is linked to V1 and V2 while V2 is linked to X1, X2 and X3 and so on. I need to find a way (algorithm or command) for getting all the biggest independent subsets of the matrix. So, in this case:

```
#   X1  X2  X3 
#   1   0   0  V1
#   1   1   1  V2  
#   0   1   0  V3
#   0   0   1  V4
```

and:

```
#   X4
#   1  V5
#   1  V6
```

and:

```
#   X5  X6 
#   1   0   V7
#   1   1   V8  
#   1   0   V9
#   0   1   V10
```

Do you have any hint? I guess there's already some library or function to use either from graph analysis or linear algebra.

Comment: Please provide that `data frame` so we can try to help you

Comment: well, it's a matrix as I wrote there `matrix(c(1,0,0,0,0,0, 1,1,1,0,0,0, 0,1,0,0,0,0, 0,0,1,0,0,0, 0,0,0,1,0,0, 0,0,0,1,0,0, 0,0,0,0,1,0, 0,0,0,0,1,1, 0,0,0,0,1,0, 0,0,0,0,0,1),10,6,byrow=TRUE)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you hinted we can do this with igraph:

```
# dummy data
df1 <- read.table(text = "  X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6
V1  1   0   0   0   0   0
                  V2    1   1   1   0   0   0
                  V3    0   1   0   0   0   0
                  V4    0   0   1   0   0   0
                  V5    0   0   0   1   0   0
                  V6    0   0   0   1   0   0
                  V7    0   0   0   0   1   0
                  V8    0   0   0   0   1   1
                  V9    0   0   0   0   1   0
                  V10   0   0   0   0   0   1
                  ")

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(igraph)

# make graph object
gg <- 
  df1 %>% 
  add_rownames(var = "V") %>% 
  gather(X, value, -V) %>% 
  filter(value == 1) %>% 
  graph.data.frame

# split based on clusters of graph
lapply(
  sapply(split(clusters(gg)$membership,
               clusters(gg)$membership), names),
  function(i)
  df1[intersect(rownames(df1), i),
      intersect(colnames(df1), i),
      drop = FALSE])

# $`1`
#    X1 X2 X3
# V1  1  0  0
# V2  1  1  1
# V3  0  1  0
# V4  0  0  1
# 
# $`2`
#    X4
# V5  1
# V6  1
# 
# $`3`
#     X5 X6
# V7   1  0
# V8   1  1
# V9   1  0
# V10  0  1
```